# Modify user selection on click event on an <a> element?

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on the text in the div element i am able to modify the selection. However this is not possible with a link element. Is there a way I can make this work without modifying the html?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', click, true)

function click(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
}

setInterval(() => {
  let selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.modify('extend', 'forward', "documentboundary");
}, 100);
```

```html
<div>text in div tag</div>
<a href="">text in a tag</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', click, true)

function click(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
}

setInterval(() => {
  let selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.modify('extend', 'forward', "documentboundary");
}, 100);
```

```css
a {
  user-select: text;
}
```

```html
<div>text in div tag</div>
<a href="">text in a tag</a>
```